# App engine is not serving images of public folder in react

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

I hosted a react app in app engine , and i have a lot of pictures in the public folder how are displayed correctly in my local machine , but when i deploy it in standard environnement , all the files are deployed , i checked the sources in url images and he serve them but they seems corrupted (when i download them) maybe i did something wrong in the configuration ? the only thing that i can acess is the favicon . this is what i get in source .
[image: source image]

and my app.yaml is :

```
runtime: nodejs12   
service: default    
instance_class: F4_1G
handlers:
   - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static

   - url: /assets
    static_dir: build/assets

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `app.yaml` does not have a handler for `/media`. So the GCP returns `index.html` when accessing `viper8.JPG`. Add handler for `/media`.